# VB.NET Open word document

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET how do you open a word/PDF doc? I used to have the code and I remember it was very short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is an app registered to handle .PDF or .DOC files, you could use the following:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\path\filename.pdf")
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\path\filename.doc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) (Visual Studio Tools for Office)?